# mysql select from 3 tables where not all tables contain infos in the same amount of rows (Inner Join?!)

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Looks like I am not able to understand some of the solutions given here and in other places, so I decided to ask my own question.

I have three tables. Like this:

```
table1
id      name        active
123     item1       1
234     item2       0
345     item3       1       <--- not in table2!!
456     item4       1
567     item5       1

table2
id      item_id     instock     variants        deliverytimes
1       123         0           S               21days
2       123         1           M               21days
3       123         2           L               21days
4       456         1           white           10days
5       456         0           black           10days
6       234         0           yellow          sold
7       456         1           green           sold
8       456         0           red             sold
9       567         0           big             sold

table3
id      item_id     description
1       123         Cool Shirt
2       234         Collectors Box
3       345         Comicbook
4       456         Basecap OneSize
5       567         Cool-Mug
```

I tried several attempts from LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN etc. that all ended up with multiple results that are not DISTINCT in the ID of the first table that I need nor they were complete. Means that if table2 does not comntain item of table1 it won't show in the result.

The closest I got is this:

```
select * from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM table2
    where (deliverytimes!='sold' OR instock>0) LIMIT 1 ) t2 
    ON t1.id=t2.item_id,
table3 t3
where t1.active = '1' 
and t1.id = t2.item_id and t3.item_id = t1.id;
```

In the end I need a list of:

"id, name, description"

```
result (as I would like it to be)
id      name        description
123     item1       Cool Shirt
345     item3       Comicbook
456     item4       Basecap OneSize
```

that does need to meet this requirements:

"item needs to be t1.active=1"
 and 
 "if items has rows in t2 show only if one row equals (instock>0 or deliverytimes!=sold)"
 and
 **"if item has no rows in t2 show as long as t1.active=1"**

Last one is the problem. I never get distinct t1.id when I use other than inner join and with inner join I still miss the rows that are not present in t2 but are still active=1.

Comment: which column you desire ?

Comment: why do you have table3?  you can save descriptions in the first table

Comment: this is all just a bit simpler than it is in reality, because the descriptions are present in different languages. So table 3 contains multiple descriptions per item (for each language). But I did cut it short to make it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting to write a query think about what data you want to show. In your case you want to show data from table1 and table3, so join these and select from them. The criteria on table2 belong in the WHERE clause.

The criteria on table2 are:

- either no entry in t2 exists
- or an entry in t2 exists with instock > 0 or deliverytimes != sold

This means one EXISTS clause, one NOT EXISTS clause, both combined with OR.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t3.description
from t1
join t3 on t3.item_id = t1.item_id
where t1.active = 1
and 
(
  not exists
  (
    select *
    from t2
    where t2.item_id = t1.item_id
  )
  or
  exists
  (
    select *
    from t2
    where t2.item_id = t1.item_id
    and (instock > 0 or deliverytimes != 'sold')
  )
);
```

Comment: That sounds logical. Will try it straight away.

Comment: That infact does all I need.

Thank you very much.

Only one thing I wonder is if there will be a big issue on parsetime, since I will have 2 selects on each row I fetch in the first select.
But I guess it will be no problem since I cache the php output until the products change.
Will keep an eye on that.

Comment: OK, now I am testing on this thing on a real life filled database and it results in 24 seconds sometimes up to 140 seconds querytime, wich is because it need to look up 24million rows with every product page that need to be fetched from sql.
This will be cached and up to the next stock update it should be not fetched again. But still it is a really high query time.

It is clearly because it does a full search on the t2 for each row of t1 wich results in a multiple of the old querytime. I wonder if I can reduce time if I use better chosen indexes on the t2 table? Right now index is set to t2.id

Comment: That was fairly quick. I tried to set index to t2.item_id because that is what we are looking up, right?! And it went straight down from 24seconds to 4seconds.

But still, I do not really understand indexes and hwo they work. So I will read some more on the mysql manpages ...

If someone has further ideas on how to produce better querytimes I am willing to test .

Comment: t1.id should be the primary key of t1, so there would automatically be an index on it. t1.item_id and t2.item_id should be foreign key to items.id, so there should also be indexes on these fields automatically. I am surprised to hear there weren't. This means you didn't really establish the connection between the tables properly and it was possible for t2.item_id to have a nonsense value rather than an existing item ID. That should never be the case.

Comment: Once you have the keys installed, you can add further indexes, such as t1(active,item_id). With this index, the DBMS can look up active records there, find the according item IDs on the fly and could search in t2 without having to look into t1 before. So such composite indexes can really speed up queries. If you even added t1.name to the index, the table wouldn't even have to be read at all, because all the info needed would be in the index. That would make the index rather large, though, and I would only do that if I needed exectly these three fields very often or had performance issues here.

Comment: Hi Thorsten.
You are right t2.id was the primary automatic. But I have to select the index seperatly, so I did set it to t2.item_id.

I could not find any way to connect the mysql tables so that it would be impossible to generate bogus id. But that is getting checked within php.
I know the database tables can be connected from earlier times when I used iHTML and Access-Databases, but I havent looked too deep in mysql, since I was only adapting things from existing scripts up to now. But I need some special tools that simply do not exist in the open source world, so I am now developing myself.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) as ID, t1.name, t3.description
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.item_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.item_id
```

if you want to filter you result with active = 1 and != soled filter in where clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) as ID, t1.name, t3.description
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.item_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.item_id
WHERE t1.active = 1 AND t2.deliverytimes != 'sold'

OR

SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) as ID, t1.name, t3.description
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.item_id = t1.id AND t2.deliverytimes != 'sold'
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.item_id
WHERE t1.active = 1
```

Comment: Well that has still the problem that I will not get the details on that item that is not present in table2.

Comment: U MEAN U WANT TO SELECT ALL RECORD WHICH IS NOT IN TABLE 2??

Comment: your last addition still does not give me the items that do not have an entry in table2 nor gives it distinct t1.id back.

Comment: ADD DISTINCT(t1.id) as ID in select field

Answer (score 0):

You can try to link table1 with table2 using Left outer join (this will make sure you will get all records from table1). And now link tbale3 as inner join, this will make sure to get all records which are related with table1.

Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 and Table1 INNER JOIN table3.

Above is my assumption, you can try the above logic.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I tried it and I got all items of table1 -> Cool
But I got all items of table1 multiple times as soon as they are present multiple times in table2.

Thats why I tried to LIMIT 1 in the INNER JOIN, because I only need to verify if the item is in table2 the requiremets are met for one row (thants enough at this point), and if not present in table2 it only need to be active=1 in table1.

Is it possible to LIMIT a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Can you try below query:SELECT        table1.id, table1.name ,table3.description
FROM            table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
            table2 ON table1.id = table2.item_id INNER JOIN            
   table3 ON table2.item_id = table3.name

   GROUP BY  table1.id, table1.name ,table3.description